# How to check which table is called which trigger in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have ten tables and five triggers in my database. I don't know the trigger name, but I need to edit the trigger. So I need to know which table is called to which trigger? Using,

```
SELECT tgname 
FROM pg_trigger;
```

we can print all the trigger name. But it did not show which table is called to which trigger. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) You already have two answers: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154683/how-to-check-which-table-is-called-which-trigger-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

The below query is used to get the information about trigger from `informational_schema`.

```
select * from information_schema.triggers;
```

The  above command shows trigger_catalog, trigger_schema, trigger_name, event_manipulation, event_object_schema, event_object_table, action_statement, action_timing.

When we use the below command it shows only the "trigger name and table name".

```
test=> select trigger_name, event_object_table from information_schema.triggers;
      trigger_name       | event_object_table 
-------------------------+--------------------
 employees_trig1         | employees
 emp_audit               | emp_view
 add_log_current_trigger | account_current
 employees_trig2         | employees
 emp_audit               | emp_view
 add_log_current_trigger | account_current
 last_name_changes       | employees
 last_name_changes       | employees
 employees_trig1         | employees
 emp_audit               | emp_view
 add_log_current_trigger | account_current
(11 rows)
```

Comment: This is essentially a copy of Craig's answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/154685/1822

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query, It will show the user defined triggers with detailed description.

```
SELECT event_object_table,trigger_name,event_manipulation,action_statement,action_timing FROM information_schema.triggers ORDER BY event_object_table,event_manipulation;
```

It will give the trigger name, table name, event manipulation, action and action timing.